# APMO 2020 Geometry Problem | Proving lines to be concurrent

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, circles, angle

**PROBLEM**
Let $\Gamma$ be the **circumcircle** of $∆ABC$. Let $D$ be a point on the side $BC$. The tangent to $\Gamma$ at $A$ intersects the parallel line to $BA$ through $D$ at point $E$. The segment $CE$ intersects $\Gamma$ again at $F$. Suppose $B$, $D$, $F$, $E$ are [**concyclic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concyclic_points). Prove that $AC, BF, DE$ are concurrent.

---

**MY APPROACH**
Let $X$ be some point on tangent line then, $$\angle XAB=\angle ACB=\angle ACD \quad(1)$$
Since $AB ||DE$, we cany say that $$\angle AED=\angle XAB \quad(2)$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can say that
$$\angle AED=\angle ACD$$
Therefore $ADCE$ is cyclic.

Consider the Circles of $BDEF$, Circles of $ADCE$ and Circumcircle of $∆ABC$. We see that $AC,BF$ and $DE$ are the radical axes of these circles which means they are concurrent at the radical Centre.

Hence, Proved!

---

But [APMO](https://www.apmo-official.org/)-$2020$ haven't included my solution in their [Official Answers](https://www.apmo-official.org/problems). Is something wrong with my Proof?

---

**DIAGRAM**
[image: Diagram]

Comment: @Rohit Singh thanks for editing

Comment: Nice proof! I'll note that you can make it *slightly* simpler by showing $A$, $D$, $C$, $E$ are concyclic via $\angle CDE\cong\angle CAE$, using very similar arguments. This eliminates the need to introduce the point $X$. (BTW: Introducing $X$ requires a little more specificity than "some point on [the] tangent line". If $X$ were on the other side of $A$ than you have drawn, then your argument would need a slight adjustment.)

Comment: @Blue yeah I think it's more simple,Thanks

Comment: Your figure is correct, but $D$ looks to be the foot of the altitude issued from $A$...

Answer (score 3):

You have a beautiful, neat proof for this problem, and it is absolutely correct, in fact it looks much more neat than the official solutions. There is nothing wrong with your solution.

But when exams are created, the creators do not know all the possible solutions to a problem, and they don't list all of them. However, as we try to solve them we can discover many new proofs which were not originally given as official solutions.

This is your own solution to the problem, and it doesn't have to be among the official solutions. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine. By the way, it use with great ingenuity the hypothesis that e , , ,  are concyclic via the property of radical center.